# Structured Exceptions (SE) from standard library calls

Tags: c++, exception, crt, seh, structured-exception

I've got code that calls ::fgetpos, which results in a kernel exception that can't be caught (I have option /ehs in my VS 2008 project).  But I can't help think that standard library routines should **never** throw these kinds of exceptions.

**update**: I've tried calling ::fgetpos(0, &foo), which is clearly wrong, and I indeed received a kernel-level exception.  I'm baffled.  Why would the C++ standard library not perform the most basic of argument checks (check for null-pointer) and raise a std::invalid_argument?

Do any standard library routines perform such basic checks, or do they all happily cause program termination?

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `fgetpos`?  Standard Library functions can (often) do whatever they like if you provide invalid arguments.

Comment: Undefined behavior can do whatever it wants. I suspect when you call it, some invariant doesn't hold so your get your exception; not their fault you used the function wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would the C++ standard library not perform the most basic of argument checks (check for null-pointer)

Because you can do that yourself if you need the check. The philosophy of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't need. If I'm a smart programmer and will never pass invalid arguments to the function, why should I have my program's performance potentially suffer with needless checks?

This is why `std::vector`, for example, provides both `operator[]` and `at()`, where the latter performs a bounds-check and the former doesn't. If you need the check, add it.